# sbt rpm:packageBin not working in MacOS BigSur or newer

Tags: sbt, rpmbuild

Before upgrading macOS to Big Sur, I used to create a link in /usr/lib/ folder that pointed to rpm tools folder:
*sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/{VERSION}/lib/rpm/ /usr/lib/rpm*

which allowed me to build rpm:
*sbt rpm:packageBin*
(the rpmbuild is assuming the rpm tools are installed under /usr/lib/rpm)

In newer macOS, /usr/lib folder is read-only so I am unable to create the link. Is there a way to specify rpmbuild tools folder (overwrite the default)?